# On linux, how can I create script to reboot server if it loses internet for x hours?

Tags: linux, scripting

I have ubuntu server that has some services that only come back after loosing internet for an extended period of time with a reboot.  Does anyone have a script that can reboot server if lose internet for like 2 hours?
Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by rebooting the server? is it supposed to bring the connectivity back up? rebooting the server just for that reason alone seems unnecessary. Just referring to any computer (specially the one you can reboot on a whim) in your question as a "server" does not automatically make such question a good fit for SF

Comment: You should fix the service and explain what service you are talking about. Rebooting your server just because certain service does not work is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [watchdog daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/watchdog.8.html). It allows you to define a custom command to test whether the server should reboot (or execute a different repair binary). That command will be a script that tests whether Internet connection has been up for the past two hours (for instance, you can run a script on cron that pings an external server and stores the date and time of the last successful ping). See [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/watchdog.conf) for configuration details.